# fadeIn() elements in array, randomly (ie, not in order), at different times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have several sentences written, all "words" within  tags, all with the same class. I have managed to fill an array with all the elements. However, all appear at the same time, and all in order down the paragraph in sequential order (ie, if element 5 is the first printed, n+1 element will always be greater than 5, and so on)

Also, in my for loop, if my for(var i=0;**i < numElements**;i++) .....32 is the number of unique elements. I must set numElements WAY larger than 32. IE all elements do not appear unless numElements >=90.  Why is this?

Attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var spanArray = [];
    var spanLength, index;
    /* Populate array with all elements of class .fadeIn */
    $(".fadeIn").each(function() {
        spanArray.push(this);   
    })

    spanLength = (spanArray.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < 33; i++) {

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (spanArray.length));  
            $(spanArray[index]).delay(400).fadeTo(500,1, function() {
                $(spanArray).splice(index,1);
   });
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwjfbq5m/)

basically:
**all elements appear at same time**
**numElements does not display all elements unless 
numElements >>> actualNumElements**

EX: [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n427mLb8/)

Comment: What is the question exactly?  In the fiddle, they don't all appear at the same time - or is that what you want to achieve with your code above?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for all wondering!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#contact").click(function() {

    $(".fadeIn").each(function() {
        var word = this;

        setTimeout(function() {

            $(word).css("opacity","1");
        }, Math.random() * 3000)

});

});
```